# How found iPad with iOS 8 is setup Face Time

Tags: ipad, ios8

As You know by iOS 8 user can answer calls in iPad.
In older version I was checking call ability by this code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:+11111"]]
```

But in iOs 8, this method returns true! I have 2 questions about this feature:

Really I can make call from application by iPad?

How can I check if user did not setup face time account?

Comment: Have you found any official apple documentation about this? Thanks!

Comment: Here's the behavior I've observed:  When I have Continuity setup and iPad can make calls via my local iPhone, tel: links work and complete the call.  This can be done either within a web browser (an HTML tel: url) or natively via a button click.


If continuity is not setup, HTML tel: links launch Facetime but then nothing happens.  tel: links launched via native functionality just don't do anything at all.


I still have the same question as you regarding checking if Continuity is setup and can actually make calls.